# How fix language change issues in production when no error in console using next-i18next?

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-i18next

my changeLanguage function is not working in production. Using the debug functionality of i18n i do not have any warning, more so the language change is detected correctly each time i click on the select menu.
i have log locale on the console and it returns undefined
Can someone explain to me what i do wrong, please? See below my changeLanguage

```
 const changeLanguage = (e) => {
    const locale = e.target.value;
     i18n.changeLanguage(locale);
    router.push(router.pathname, router.asPath, { locale });
  };
```

Comment: How is changeLanguage invoked?

Comment: Hi @adrai yes, changeLanguage is invoked . I managed to fix the undefined matter by lifting up my locale in my layout component then pass it as props to my navbar . However it is still not changing the language. There is one this that i have noticed different from localhost is that the lang tag in the html is not changing in production.  :)

Comment: one more thing i have tried to add the the route /en-us in production it returns error 404

Comment: solved here: https://github.com/i18next/next-i18next/issues/1910

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to have a function to change the locale.

With nextjs you have `router()`, this fit perfectly to any cases.

Also, you have `<Link>` with `locale` property.

1st possible way - change locale with URL. So, you can `.map` your locales with links and then change it.

```
<Link href='/test' locale={router.locale} key="your_key">
 <a>test</a>
</Link>
```

2nd possible way - change with function

```
router.push("/test", null, {locale: "your_desired_locale_or_variable"})
```

Your locales are defined in your `config` file, probably you have `en` locale and not `en-us`

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: Great Illia! I was forced to use the Link but it wasn't the best choice for me